# Splitting a table by groups SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a list of businesses,with many columns, but these are the important ones:

```
| name     |stars | review_count |
| -------- | -----| -----------  |
| First    | 3.0  |        1235  |
| Second   | 4.4  |          45  |
| third    | 2.5  |         123  |
```

So want to goup it by it's stars values like

```
|stars  | review_count |
| ----- |  ----------- |
|  < 3  |         1358 |
|  >=3  |           45 |
```

I've tried with

```
select sum(review_count), stars
from business 
group by (2<=stars and stars <3)  or stars >3
```

But didn't worked.

Comment: It is SQL (title) or S(tag)? If SQL please tag your SQL Engine

Comment: In your question you mention a column `stars` but in the code I see `review_count`. Also what do you mean by *any*?  Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: Ok, I'll change everything to make it clearer. ty

Comment: The result for <3 should be 123 and for >=3 should be 1280

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression to create the 2 groups and group by that:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN stars < 3 THEN '<3' ELSE '>=3' END stars, 
       SUM(review_count) review_count 
FROM business 
GROUP BY 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9d1603ab0e92e1cf32c33f896e5fea66).